How to set up port forwarding with UWF?
I have a server running Ubuntu. It has a Wifi adapter (interface wlo1) and an ethernet port (interface enp44s0). The Wifi network is 10.42.1.0/24 and the wired network is 10.42.0.0/24. The server has IP 10.42.0.1 and 10.42.1.1.
I have a workstation on the wired network with a web server running. Its IP is 10.42.0.216. From the server I can connect to the workstation's web page no problem.
I have a phone connect to the Wifi. Its IP is 10.42.1.111.
I want to setup port forwarding so that when I connect to 10.42.1.1 from my phone, it redirect to the workstation and the web server running on it. Easy right?
I use UFW on the server (it comes with Ubuntu). Surprisingly UFW can't set up port forwarding (uncomplicated firewall my a*s). Following online tutorials this is what I tried:

Uncomment the line net/ipv4/ip_forward=1 in the /etc/ufw/sysctl.conf file.
Set DEFAULT_FORWARD_POLICY="ACCEPT" in the /etc/default/ufw file.
Allow both port 80 and 443 with an UFW rule.
Add the following at the beginning of the /etc/ufw/before.rules file:

*nat
:PREROUTING ACCEPT [0:0]
-A PREROUTING -d 10.42.1.1 -p tcp --dport 80  -j DNAT --to-destination 10.42.0.216:80
-A PREROUTING -d 10.42.1.1 -p tcp --dport 443 -j DNAT --to-destination 10.42.0.216:443
-A POSTROUTING -s 10.42.0.0/24 -j MASQUERADE
COMMIT

And here is the result:
ufw status numbered
Status: active

     To                         Action      From
     --                         ------      ----
[ 1] Anywhere on eno2           ALLOW FWD   Anywhere on enp44s0       
[ 2] Anywhere on enp44s0        ALLOW IN    Anywhere                  
[ 3] 6881/tcp on eno2           ALLOW IN    Anywhere                  
[ 4] 53 on wlo1                 ALLOW IN    Anywhere                  
[ 5] 67/udp on wlo1             ALLOW IN    Anywhere                  
[ 6] 8888/tcp on wlo1           ALLOW IN    Anywhere                  
[ 7] 445/tcp on wlo1            ALLOW IN    Anywhere                  
[ 8] Anywhere on eno2           ALLOW FWD   Anywhere on wlo1          
[ 9] 443/tcp                    ALLOW IN    Anywhere                  
[10] 80/tcp                     ALLOW IN    Anywhere                  
[11] 443/tcp (v6)               ALLOW IN    Anywhere (v6)             
[12] 80/tcp (v6)                ALLOW IN    Anywhere (v6)  

Chain PREROUTING (policy ACCEPT 10211 packets, 579K bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
   11   660 DNAT       tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            10.42.1.1            tcp dpt:80 to:10.42.0.216:80
    0     0 DNAT       tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            10.42.1.1            tcp dpt:443 to:10.42.0.216:443
 9795  541K DOCKER     all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            ADDRTYPE match dst-type LOCAL

Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
    0     0 DOCKER     all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0           !127.0.0.0/8          ADDRTYPE match dst-type LOCAL

Chain POSTROUTING (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
    0     0 MASQUERADE  all  --  *      !docker0  172.17.0.0/16        0.0.0.0/0           
    2   120 MASQUERADE  all  --  *      !br-1972fe7a2df1  172.18.0.0/16        0.0.0.0/0           
    6  1192 MASQUERADE  all  --  *      *       10.42.0.0/24         0.0.0.0/0           
    0     0 MASQUERADE  tcp  --  *      *       172.18.0.2           172.18.0.2           tcp dpt:9999

Chain DOCKER (2 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
    0     0 RETURN     all  --  docker0 *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
    0     0 RETURN     all  --  br-1972fe7a2df1 *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
    1    60 DNAT       tcp  --  !br-1972fe7a2df1 *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:9999 to:172.18.0.2:9999


And with all that when I enter 10.42.1.1 in my phone's browser address bar I can't get a connection. What did I miss? What test procedure or tools can I use to troubleshoot the issue?
Edit: I looked at it with Wireshark and I noticed that when I try to connect with my phone the SYN is immediately answered with an ICMP destination unreachable port unreachable. I don't know what is causing it.
Edit: Here is a diagram of the setup.


I finally figured out what the problem was. For those stumbling on the same problem here is the explanation and solution.
Iptables is dead and has been replaced with nftables. The iptables command is still there but it is an alias to nftables. Iptables still works for the most part but is just the tip of the iceberg. If something else is setting firewall rules with nftables then you won't see it with iptables and you will be left wondering why your iptables rules don't work the way they should.
And indeed there is something setting nftables rules behind your back. Ubuntu comes with NetworkManager. This is what I used to let my Ubuntu box share its internet connection with other computers on the LAN and setup my Wifi hot spot. In order to share internet connection the NetworkManager has to set nftables rules. You can see them if you type nft list ruleset.
# This table is for sharing internet connection with computers connected to the wifi hot spot
table ip nm-shared-wlo1 {
    chain nat_postrouting {
        type nat hook postrouting priority srcnat; policy accept;
        ip saddr 10.42.1.0/24 ip daddr != 10.42.1.0/24 masquerade
    }

    chain filter_forward {
        type filter hook forward priority filter; policy accept;
        ip daddr 10.42.1.0/24 oifname "wlo1" ct state { established, related } accept
        ip saddr 10.42.1.0/24 iifname "wlo1" accept
        iifname "wlo1"    oifname "wlo1" accept
        
        # This is the problem
        iifname "wlo1" reject
        oifname "wlo1" reject
    }
}

# This table is for sharing internet connection with computers connected to the LAN
table ip nm-shared-enp44s0 {
    chain nat_postrouting {
        type nat hook postrouting priority srcnat; policy accept;
        ip saddr 10.42.0.0/24 ip daddr != 10.42.0.0/24 masquerade
    }

    chain filter_forward {
        type filter hook forward priority filter; policy accept;
        ip daddr 10.42.0.0/24 oifname "enp44s0" ct state { established, related } accept
        ip saddr 10.42.0.0/24 iifname "enp44s0" accept
        iifname "enp44s0" oifname "enp44s0" accept

        # This is the problem
        iifname "enp44s0" reject
        oifname "enp44s0" reject
    }
}

NetworkManager set rules so that packets can't flow from the wifi (wlo1) to the LAN (enp44s0) and vice versa. This is why the port forwarding can not work.
The solution is to instruct NetworkManager not to set any firewall rules. You can do that by editing /etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf and adding the following line in the [main] section firewall-backend=none.
But now you have to setup your firewall yourself or you won't have internet connection sharing. You can do it with either nftables or firewalld (I didn't try the later).
For nftables all you need is a script like this one:
#!/usr/sbin/nft -f

# Flush the rule set
flush ruleset



# This table is for sharing internet connection with computers connected to the wifi hot spot
table ip nm-shared-wlo1 {
    chain nat_postrouting {
        type nat hook postrouting priority srcnat; policy accept;
        ip saddr 10.42.1.0/24 ip daddr != 10.42.1.0/24 masquerade
    }

    chain filter_forward {
        type filter hook forward priority filter; policy accept;
        ip daddr 10.42.1.0/24 oifname "wlo1" ct state { established, related } accept
        ip saddr 10.42.1.0/24 iifname "wlo1" accept
        iifname "wlo1"    oifname "wlo1" accept
        iifname "enp44s0" oifname "wlo1"    accept
        iifname "wlo1"    oifname "enp44s0" accept
        iifname "wlo1" reject
        oifname "wlo1" reject
    }
}



# This table is for sharing internet connection with computers connected to the LAN
table ip nm-shared-enp44s0 {
    chain nat_postrouting {
        type nat hook postrouting priority srcnat; policy accept;
        ip saddr 10.42.0.0/24 ip daddr != 10.42.0.0/24 masquerade
    }

    chain filter_forward {
        type filter hook forward priority filter; policy accept;
        ip daddr 10.42.0.0/24 oifname "enp44s0" ct state { established, related } accept
        ip saddr 10.42.0.0/24 iifname "enp44s0" accept
        iifname "enp44s0" oifname "enp44s0" accept
        iifname "enp44s0" oifname "wlo1"    accept
        iifname "wlo1"    oifname "enp44s0" accept
        iifname "enp44s0" reject
        oifname "enp44s0" reject
    }
}

You notice I added rules to allow packets to flow from Wifi to LAN and vice versa. I'm sure I could have found a less redundant way to do it but it works.
Now you can setup port forwarding using iptables, nftables or firewalld. To do it with nftables you can add this section to your script. You don't need post routing.
# Forward incoming connections on ports 80 and 443 on wifi to workstation on LAN
# This computer is 10.42.1.1 on the wifi
# Workstation is 10.42.0.216 the LAN
table ip nat {
    chain PREROUTING {
        type nat hook prerouting priority dstnat; policy accept;
        meta l4proto tcp ip daddr 10.42.1.1 tcp dport 80  dnat to 10.42.0.216
        meta l4proto tcp ip daddr 10.42.1.1 tcp dport 443 dnat to 10.42.0.216
    }
}

